# jQuery Convert string of values to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Please consider this string:

```
['2012-2','2012-3','2012-4','2013-1','2013-2','2013-3','2013-4','2014-1']
```

I return this string from a web method and I want to loop on this values and I write this:

```
var tr = '<tr><td>Title</td>';
$.each(arrPeriods, function (index, value) {
     tr += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
});
tr += '</tr>';
```

And I get this error:

> JavaScript runtime error: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected

I think the problem is I should convert the string to an array but I don't know how I can do this. Please help me solve my problem.

Comment: What is a "web method"? Why don't you just return the data in a format that you can use instead?

Comment: You can return it as array, instead of string

Comment: I use `ASP.Net` to get data from server and I should return string

Comment: You can use `split` to convert string to array

Comment: What does it mean you should return string? Is that mandatory ?

Comment: Is the `['2012-2','2012-3','2012-4','2013-1','2013-2','2013-3','2013-4','2014-1']` thing already an array? Is it what you call `arrPeriods`?

Comment: @Arian Then use [JSON](http://json.org/).

Comment: `var array = eval(arrPeriods);`

It will work, but there are better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must replace all your 
`"'"` to 
`"\""` Then you can use JSON.parse() for convert your string into an array. Just like this:

```
var answer = "['2012-2','2012-3','2012-4','2013-1','2013-2','2013-3','2013-4','2014-1']";
answer = answer.split("'").join("\"");

var arrPeriods = JSON.parse(answer);

var tr = $('<tr><td>Title</td></tr>');

$.each(arrPeriods, function(index, value) {
  tr.append('<td>' + value + '</td>');
});

$('table').append(tr);
```

Comment: Please stop recommending the "fixing" of non-JSON. Fix the source, not the symptoms. According to the question, the OP has access to the backend where this string comes from. It would be much more sensible to just fix the backend to produce proper JSON in the first place.

Comment: @str But  then this question will not be raised, if backend response can be in array

Comment: @SudharshanNair And that would be a good thing right? Fix it properly on the backend instead of adding hacky code to the frontend.

Comment: @str Obviously you are correct, But for short time fix, if user needs solution, then this can be applied. All things cannot be changed quick as we think

Comment: @SudharshanNair I don't want to know how many "short time [fixes]" have been out there for years :-)

Comment: Sorry I have another question. I really return this string:`[{name: 'price', Title: 'MyTitle', data:[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0.00]}]` and how I can convert this string to json?

Comment: @Arian Always for converting string to JSON you must use JSON.parse the problem with your string is that is not a valid JSON, please try to valid your JSON so you can convert it without any problem, you can use this page for example: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @BrankVictoria "for converting string to JSON you must use JSON.parse" I think you mean: For converting *JSON* to *JavaScript object or array* you must use `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 1):

You must use jQuery method `.append()` instead to add `td`'s after converting your string to an array.

**NOTE: I suggest to return an array from backend if possible it will be more efficient. This solution is just a temporary fix for now**

```js
var arrPeriods = "['2012-2', '2012-3', '2012-4', '2013-1', '2013-2', '2013-3', '2013-4', '2014-1']";
var myArray = arrPeriods.replace(/\[|\]|'/g, '').split(',');

var tr = $('<tr><td>Title</td></tr>');

$.each(myArray, function(index, value) {
  tr.append('<td>' + value + '</td>');
});

$('table').append(tr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border=1></table>
```

Comment: Is that what you looking for Arian ?

Comment: I think the problem is I have : '['2012-2', '2012-3', '2012-4', '2013-1', '2013-2', '2013-3', '2013-4', '2014-1']'. I mean the string of array

Comment: First thing is its not array, its string

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki It looks better now

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Still  in your output, we can see brackets for first and last td.

Comment: Sorry I have another question. I really return this string:[{name: 'price', Title: 'MyTitle', data:[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0.00]}] and how I can convert this string to json?

Comment: @Arian Why are you returning `JSON`. Why don't you directly return `array`

Comment: because I'm using classic ASP.Net and you right if I use `MVC`

Answer (score -1):

See the comments.

```js
var arrPeriods = "['2012-2', '2012-3', '2012-4', '2013-1', '2013-2', '2013-3', '2013-4', '2014-1']";
arrPeriods = arrPeriods.replace(/'/g, '"'); // Clean the string into an acceptable JSON string
arrPeriods = JSON.parse(arrPeriods); // Parse the JSON string

var $tr = $('<tr><td>Title</td></tr>'); // Create the row
var $table = $('<table></table>')
  .append($tr);

// No need to use jQuery's .each
arrPeriods.forEach(function (date) {
  $tr.append('<td>' + date + '</td>');
});

$('body').append($table);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```